# :last-child doesn't target last div

Tags: css

When i target div with :last-child it dosn't works. With :first-child it's OK. :last-of-type works too. Any ideas? Thanks.
 
HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="vienas" style="text-aling:justify">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
  </div>
  <div class="vienas" style="text-aling:justify">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do e</p
  </div>
  <div class="vienas" style="text-aling:justify">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.vienas:last-child { font-weight:bold; }
```

Comment: Works when I try it; only the last one is bold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second `<p>` at the end, take a look, `>` is missing and fixing that probably fix your issue too:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod</p>
```