# Is it possible to solve the problem without class for div , :last-child?

Tags: html, css

I want to paint the last one div but I couldn't!

```css
div:first-child {
  background-image: linear-gradient(purple, violet);
}

div:last-child {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, yellow, black);
}
```

```html
<div>first div</div>
<div>second div</div>
<div class="box">third div</div>
<div id="color">fourth div</div>
<div>fifth div</div>
```

I found a link but they didn't help me:

> [:last-child doesn't target last div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26927837/last-child-doesnt-target-last-div)
> [:last-child not working as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995362/last-child-not-working-as-expected)

Is it possible to solve the problem without **class**? (That one will be a class named **parent** and the second class will be a **child** that will be inside the div of the parent class?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that those `div`s are really first and last children (take a look at elements panel in dev tools). For example, wrap them in `<main>` element.

```css
div:first-child {
    background-image: linear-gradient(purple,violet);
}

div:last-child{
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg,yellow,black);
}
```

```html
 <main>
    <div>first div</div>
    <div>second div</div>
    <div class="box">third div</div>
    <div id="color">fourth div</div>
    <div>fifth div</div>
 </main>
```

Comment: Why does it initially color the first div?

Comment: because it matches the selection. When you look at the renedered DOM you'll see that in your code there are other elements before and after `div`s. That's why it doesn't apply to your divs.

Comment: do you mean the "class" and "id" ?